# How do i server static files relative to subdirectory index files in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
I have a structure like so
/applications
/applications/testRoute
/applications/testRoute/index.html
/applications/testRoute/test.js
/applications/server.js
```

I am running an express app with multiple angular apps in sub paths. Each SPA has an index file that kicks things off. When I run an express server from the parent directory, any index files in the sub directories tries to make its requests for static files starting at the parent directory. I should be able to use relative file paths but they all start at the root of the server. How come? As you can see in my example below (test-route) will try to request test.js from the main directory and not from /testRoute/test.js. I've tried 'test.js','./test.js/', '/test.js'. Any sub directory index file always tries to make its relative path the root of the server. How come?

```
    // server.js

    // BASE SETUP
    // ==============================================

    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var app = express();
    var port    =   process.env.PORT || 8080;

    // ROUTES
    // ==============================================

    // sample route with a route the way we're used to seeing it
    app.use('/testRoute', express.static('testRoute'));


    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        var options = {
            root: __dirname + '/'
        };

        res.sendFile('index.html',options);
    });

    app.get('/test-route', function(req, res) {
        var options = {
            root: __dirname + '/testRoute'
        };

        res.sendFile('index.html',options);
    });



    app.listen(port);
    <!--Test Route Index -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <h1>Test Route</h1>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I am handling this is to make each part of the application it's own `express` application. That way, they can define their own static folders. You then just glue them all together in another `express` app with `app.use('/test-route', myTestRouteApp)`.

This is your `second-app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

module.exports = () => {
  const app = express();
  app.use('/static', express.static(...));
  ...
  return app;
};
```

This is your `app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

const secondApp = require('./second-app');

module.exports = () => {
  const app = express();
  
  app.use('/second-app', secondApp());
  ...
  return app;
};
```

So once you start your app, you can now access `/second-app/static/`.

Comment: Can they all be run on the same domain? I need to share local storage between the apps.

Comment: Added code example in my response. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: Did this do what you were looking for?